# python android script crashes in AVD device

Tags: android, python, linux

Using the android SDK manager i have installed Android 2.3.3 API10 SDK platform

Now i made a simple python script for test

```
import android
app = android.Android()
msg = "Mr. X welcome to Android!"
app.makeToast(msg)
```

but this crashes with the follwing error on the AVD device:

```
the application SL4A(process com.googlecode.android_scripting) has stopped unexpectedly, Please try again
```

any ideas where the problem could be?? sorry i am new to android scripting..

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your script just now on a real device and it works just fine. Make sure you have the lastest version of SL4A and your Python modules up to date.

There is no error in the syntax so that's ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to apps in settings and Force Stop + clear the data. This usually fixes it for me. Seems to be a bug somewhere.